# Do we have $\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial y}$ in this proof of integral factor of exact O.D.E?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading about integral factors of exact differential equations from a book. It says,

> If the integral factor of the equation $Mdx+Ndy=0$ is in the form
> $\mu=\mu(z)$ where $z=f(x,y)$. To find integral factor we use the
> following formula:
>
> $g(z)=\dfrac{M_y-N_x}{N.z_x-M.z_y}\quad,\quad\mu=e^{\int g(x)dx}$
>
> Proof:
>
> $$\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(\mu(z).M)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\mu(z).N)\Rightarrow
>  z_y\;\mu'(z).M+\mu(z).M_y=z_x.\mu'(z).N+\mu(z).N_x$$
> $$\Rightarrow\mu'(z)(M.z_y-N.z_x)=\mu(z).(N_x-M_y)\Rightarrow\frac{\mu'(z)}{\mu(z)}=\frac{M_y-N_x}{N.z_x-M.z_y}=g(z)$$
> $$\Rightarrow \int\frac{\mu'(z)}{\mu(z)}dz=\int g(z)dz\Rightarrow
>  \ln(\mu(z))=\int
> g(z)dz\Rightarrow \mu(z)=e^{\int g(z)dz}$$

I understand the calculations of the proof except for one part: When we take differentiate of $\mu(z)$ with respect to $y$ and $x$ I think we get the following (using chain rule) ,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[\mu(z)]=z_y.\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial y}\qquad\qquad\qquad\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[\mu(z)]=z_x.\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}$$

In the proof it used the other notation $\mu'(z)$ for both of $\dfrac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial\mu}{\partial y}$. Then factored it out in the second line of the proof. And  it means $\dfrac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial\mu}{\partial y}$. But, are they equal? And why?

Comment: Think again about what the chain rule means for $\mu(f(x,y))$. $\mu$ has no direct dependence on $x$ or $y$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Oh I got it, it should be $\dfrac{\partial\mu}{\partial z}$ instead?

Comment: $\mu$ is a function of a single variable. $f$ is a function of two variables. Hence, $\mu$ has a single variable derivative $\mu'(z)$ and $f$ has partial derivatives $\partial f/\partial x$, $\partial f/\partial y$. Hence, $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\mu(f(x,y)) = \mu'(f(x,y))\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

Comment: Yes. And as there is only this single variable, this can also be written as $\mu'(z)$.